# AWS S3 TransferManager doesn't exit upon completion of object transfer

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS TransferManager to upload my objects on S3 bucket using Scala programming.

My code is something like:

```
val xferMgr:TransferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(awsClient).build();

val putObjectRequest:PutObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key + fileToUpload.getName, fileToUpload);

val upload:Upload = xferMgr.upload(putObjectRequest);

val uploadResult:UploadResult = upload.waitForUploadResult();

if (uploadResult != null) {
    val uploadedS3Filename:String = uploadResult.getKey();
    println("File uploaded with key: " + uploadedS3Filename);
}
```

This code does upload objects to S3 bucket, however my problem is that the thread keeps running in the background and it doesn't end upon completion.

How do I make my program exit successfully once the upload is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS TransferManager is using multiple threads to make uploads faster by uploading multiple parts of a single file in the same time. To release the resources that manager is using you should use:

```
xferMgr.shutdownNow()
```

after your upload is finished.